# How to zip two columns, explode them and finally pivot?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two array columns (`names`, `score`). I need to explode both of them. Make names as column `name` for score(similar to pivot).

```
+------------+-------------------------+--------------------+                        
|      id    |     names               |      score         |
+------------+-------------------------+--------------------+
|ab01        |[F1 , F2, F3, F4, F5]    |[00123, 000.001, 00127, 00.0123, 111]
|ab02        |[F1 , F2, F3, F4, F5, F6]|[00124, 000.003, 00156, 00.067,  156, 254]
|ab03        |[F1 , F2, F3, F4, F5]    |[00234, 000.078, 00188, 00.0144, 188]
|ab04        |[F1 , F2, F3, F4, F5]    |[00345, 000.01112, 001567, 00.0186, 555]
```

Expected output:

```
 id       F1      F2        F3        F4    F5  F6
ab01    00123   000.001    00127    00.0123 111 null
ab02    00124   000.003    00156    00.067  156 254
ab03    00234   000.078    00188    00.0144 188 null
ab04    00345   000.01112  001567   00.0186 555 null
```

I tried zipping up names and score and then exploding them

```
combine = F.udf(lambda x, y: list(zip(x, y)),
                ArrayType(
                          StructType(
                                     [StructField("names", StringType()),
                                      StructField("score", StringType())
                                     ]
                                    )
                         )
               )

df2 = df.withColumn("new", combine("score", "names"))
         .withColumn("new", F.explode("new"))
         .select("id", 
                 F.col("new.names").alias("names"), 
                 F.col("new.score").alias("score")
                )
```

I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

I also tried exploding using rdd `flatMap()` and I still get the same error.

Is there an alternate way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df2 = df.set_index('id').apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
df3 = df2.pivot(columns='names', values='score', index='id')
```

---

df3:

```
names   F1       F2         F3      F4      F5  F6
id                      
ab01    00123   000.001     00127   00.0123 111 NaN
ab02    00123   000.003     00156   00.067  156 254
ab03    00234   000.078     00188   00.0144 188 NaN
ab04    00345   000.01112   001567  00.0186 555 NaN
```

---

**edit:**

```
x = (df.apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['names'], x['score'])), axis=1))
y = pd.DataFrame(x.values.tolist(), index=x.index).fillna("null").join(df.id)
```

or

```
x = (df.apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['names'], x['score'])), axis=1))
z = pd.DataFrame(x.values.tolist(), index=x.index).fillna("null")
y = pd.concat([df.id , z], axis=1)
```

---

y:

```
    F1      F2         F3       F4      F5  F6      id
0   00123   000.001    00127    00.0123 111 null    ab01
1   00123   000.003    00156    00.067  156 254     ab02
2   00234   000.078    00188    00.0144 188 null    ab03
3   00345   000.01112  001567   00.0186 555 null    ab04
```

Comment: Thank you. But pandas version is 0.22. This version doesn't support Series.explode

Comment: Any reasonto use pandas older version?

Comment: That's the org platform version.

Comment: Thank you. The 2nd solution helped to get the desired output in pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`arrays_zip`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#arrays_zip) function + `explode` then finally group by and pivot:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, expr, first

df1 = df.withColumn("name_score", explode(expr("arrays_zip(name, score)"))) \
       .selectExpr("id", "name_score.*")\
       .groupBy("id").pivot("name").agg(first("score"))

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+----+-----+-------+------+------+---+----+
#|id  |F1   |F2     |F3    |F4    |F5 |F6  |
#+----+-----+-------+------+------+---+----+
#|ab01|00123|0.001  |0.127 |0.0123|111|null|
#|ab04|00345|0.01112|0.1567|0.0186|555|null|
#|ab03|00234|0.078  |0.188 |0.0144|188|null|
#|ab02|00124|0.003  |0.156 |0.067 |156|254 |
#+----+-----+-------+------+------+---+----+
```

For **Spark < 2.4**:

Your UDF `combine` is OK. You get the error `TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration` because you're passing the column names as a string to the UDF, use col to pass columns:

```
df1 = df.withColumn("name_score", explode(combine(col("name"), col("score")))) \
      .selectExpr("id", "name_score.*") \
      .groupBy("id").pivot("name").agg(first("score"))
```

Comment: Thank you. I have pyspark version 2.3. Which doesnt support arrays_zip.

Answer (score 1):

You might have nulls in the dataframe. Add a check in the UDF to make sure this doesn't happen.

```
combine = F.udf(lambda x, y: list(zip(x, y)) if x is not None and y is not None else None,
                ArrayType(
                          StructType(
                                     [StructField("names", StringType()),
                                      StructField("score", StringType())
                                     ]
                                    )
                         )
               )
```